# Getting a requested URL not found error when running flask code

Tags: python, flask

Created a web app and have managed to build a function to clean up csv files from Google my Business exports.  However when I run the function with the code I have written I get the following error message:

> Not Found
>
> The requested URL was not found on the server. If you entered the URL
>   manually please check your spelling and try again.

Not sure where I am going wrong

```
mport os
import pandas as pd
from flask import Flask, request, redirect, url_for
from flask import Flask, make_response
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename

UPLOAD_FOLDER = './Downloads/gmbreports'
if not os.path.exists(UPLOAD_FOLDER):
    os.makedirs(UPLOAD_FOLDER)

ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS = 'csv'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
def allowed_file(filename):
    return '.' in filename and \
           filename.rsplit('.', 1)[1].lower() in ALLOWED_EXTENSIONS

def transform(text_file_contents):
    disc = open('clean.csv')
    disc2 = open('clean_two.csv','w')
    #cleaning up csv
    for row in disc:
        row = row.strip()
        row = row[1:-1]
        row = row.replace('""','"')
        disc2.write(row+'\n')
    disc2.close()
    disc.close()
    discovery = pd.read_csv('clean_two.csv')
    discovery_clean = discovery.iloc[1:]
    cols = list(discovery_clean.columns[4:])
    discovery_clean[cols] = discovery_clean[cols].apply(pd.to_numeric,errors='coerce')
    return discovery_clean

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload_file():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'file' not in request.files:
            flash('No file part')
            return redirect(request.url)
        file = request.files['file']
        if file.filename == '':
            flash('You need to upload a csv file')
            return redirect(request.url)
        if file and allowed_file(file.filename):
            filename = secure_filename(file.filename)
            file.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], filename))
            return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file',
                                    filename=filename))
    return '''
    <!doctype html>
    <title>Google My Business Discovery Report Builder</title>
    <h1>Upload GMB Discovery csv</h1>
    <form action="\transform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <p><input type="file" name="file">
         <input type="submit" value=Upload>
    </form>
    '''
@app.route('/transform',methods=["POST"])
def transform_view():
    request_file=request.files['file']
    request_file.save('clean.csv')
    if not request_file:
        return "No file"
    result = transform()
    print(result)

    response = make_response(result)
    response.headers["Content-Disposition"] ="attachment; filename=result.csv"
    return response


if __name__=='__main__':
    app.run()
```

Note: I get this error message after running the script and uploading a csv. The desired outcome is uploading a csv, and showing it on my screen as a cleaned up data table

Comment: what error message do you get in the terminal where you run the flask server?

Comment: @mousahalaseh not sure what you mean, If i run the script and try and upload a csv I get the Not Found error

Comment: also, it's a bad design to render HTML directly from your method. use a separate template engine (e.g. [Jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/))

Comment: how exactly do you run the app?

Comment: @mousahalaseh python main.py on bash then I get a page that allows me to upload a csv file, I upload the file and get this error message

Comment: you need to export the FLASK_APP, and then run it using either `python -m flask` or `flask run` command. Have you read the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/dev/quickstart/)?

Comment: The file is uploaded successfully?

Comment: @iJustin254 appears to be uploaded

Comment: You're redirecting here `return redirect(url_for('uploaded_file', filename=filename))`, but I don't actually see an "uploaded_file" method.  Should "uploaded_file" be "transform_view"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems here.  First, Wondercricket is correct about the form action.  It needs to be changed to "/transform".

Once that's done, you're still getting an Internal Server Error.  In this case, your `transform` function is defined as taking a single parameter, but it's not being called with one.  Simply change

`def transform(text_file_contents):`

to

`def transform():`

That should allow the upload to happen, and the transform will now run.  However, there's still one last problem.  `transform` returns a pandas DataFrame, which Flask can't use as a response.  Change

`response = make_response(result)`

to

`response = make_response(result.to_csv())`

and you should be good to go.

Comment: Also, keep in mind, if you're just running this via `python main.py` then you'll need to restart the server once you make your changes.